# color branches of dendrogram by groups in R (without h or k element)

Tags: r, dendrogram, graph-coloring, factoextra

I want to color branches of a dendrogram by specific groups that a defined in a dataframe.

```
library(reshape2)
library(factoextra) # clustering visualization 
library(dendextend)
#iris dataset
#defining colors
colori = rep(NA, length=length(iris$Species))
colori[which(iris$Species=="setosa")] = "red"
colori[which(iris$Species=="versicolor")] = "blue"
colori[which(iris$Species=="virginica")] = "yellow"

iris_dist <- dist(iris[ ,1:4],)
hc1_iris <- hclust(iris_dist,method = "average")
col_dendro_iris <- color_branches(as.dendrogram(hc1_iris),groupLabels =T, clusters = iris$Species,col=colori)

col_dendro_iris_plot <- plot(col_dendro_iris,main = "Dendrogram of normalized BLS\ncolored by manmade groups",labels = NULL,xlab = NULL)
```

That only colors the branches red. Why? How can I solve that
[image]

EDIT:
It works when I do this

```
pca_iris <- PCA(iris[ ,1:4])
colori = rep(NA, length=length(iris$Species))
colori[which(iris$Species=="versicolor")] = "red"
colori[which(iris$Species=="virginica")] = "yellow"
colori[which(iris$Species=="setosa")] = "blue"
# species <- iris$Species
iris_gr <- cbind(iris,colori)
# 
pca_iris <- fviz_pca_ind(pca_iris,
             pointshape = 21,habillage = iris$Species,
             geom.ind = c("point"),geom = c("point"),palette = iris$colori,
             title="PCA of normalized BLS\ncolored by manmade groups")
pca_iris<- pca_iris + theme(legend.position = "upper.right")
```

Just for future readers.
But actually I can't color the dendrogram in an analog way.
I do not have a `k` or `h` element for defining clusters. Like in iris, I have predefined clusters I want to color.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a dendrogram with colored branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036094/how-to-create-a-dendrogram-with-colored-branches)

Comment: Like I edited, I do not have a ```k``` or ```h``` element for defining clusters but predefined groups. In the iris example it is the specy

Comment: For predefined groups, I suggest using color_labels to color the text with this information.Also take a look at:
http://talgalili.github.io/dendextend/reference/colored_bars.html

Answer (score 5):

You should use the library `dendextend`. It has the functions for extending dendrogram objects.

Below a simple example.

```
library(dendextend)
dend_var<-as.dendrogram(hc_var)
dend_colored<-color_branches(dend_var, h=10000, k=7)
plot(dend_colored)
```

`dend_var` is a a dendrogram or hclust tree object.

`k` is used to choose the number of groups.

`h` is used to choose the height at which to cut tree.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @SlowLearning. Actually I do not have an ```h```or ```k```element. My groups a re like in iris, predefined in a data.frame

Comment: @takeITeasy When you use the dendrogram you are speaking about the hierarchical clustering. In this case you have just 4 groups, this because you have just four variables.
The dendogram starts from below to above (I say this because you will find in the down part all the variables that you use in your analysis).
I use the dendogram when I look for groups and I need to see the environment of my variables (every step is level). For example to choose the groups you should cut the dendrogram.